# Add UIImageView inside UIView at exactly centre of the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I add `UIView` which has the size equal to screen size than I add `UIImageView` to this view. I want to set this `UIImageView` at exactly centre of the `UIView`. I'm doing this programatically therefore, can't put constraints via storyboard. Below is my code:

```
UIView* viewForImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200);
UIImageView* imgcoverView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
imgcoverView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9];
imgcoverView.image = imgView.image;
[viewForImage addSubview:imgcoverView];
```

Comment: Use `CGRect rect = CGRectMake((screenRect-100)/2, (screenRect-200)/2, 100, 200);`

Answer (score 4):

```
imgcoverView.center = CGPointMake(viewForImage.frame.size.width/2,viewForImage.frame.size.height/2) ;
```

Comment: Have you seen the initialization of viewForImage.
UIView* viewForImage = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];

screenRect

Answer (score 0):

Please consider different orientation of the device. I think it's better to add as two centre constraints.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *xCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imgcoverView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewForImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[viewForImage addConstraint:xCenterConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *yCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imgcoverView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewForImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[viewForImage addConstraint:yCenterConstraint];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it By constraint !!!

set only two Constraint Horizontal center in container and Vertical center in container

Answer (score -1):

```
imgcoverView.frame = 
           CGRectMake(viewForImage.frame.origin.x + (viewForImage.frame.size.width - imgcoverView.frame.size.width)/2, 
                      viewForImage.frame.origin.y + (viewForImage.frame.size.height - imgcoverView.frame.size.height)/2,
                      imgcoverView.frame.size.width,
                      imgcoverView.frame.size.height);
```